# Compatibility issue with <!DOCTYPE html> and .clientHeight JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am experiencing issues with  when setting the height of one DIV based on .clientHeight of another DIV.

Sample of my JS below:

```
<script>
var height1 = document.getElementById("DIV1").clientHeight;
document.getElementById("DIV2").style.height = height1;
</script>
```

The weird thing is that when I remove the doctype declaration from the top of the page, the javascript performs the operation correctly (obviously I dont want to remove the doctype from the page...)

Comment: Just to clear it up: When you remove the DOCTYPE declaration, the JavaScript is performing **incorrectly**. Just because it does what you want, doesn't make it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
<script>
var height1 = document.getElementById("DIV1").clientHeight;
document.getElementById("DIV2").style.height = height1 + "px";
</script>
```

The style.height requires the length not the numeric value.

Hope this helps someone else...